# How do I delete a chat room?

Tags: support, chat

I am facing a problem. The problem is that I want to delete the chat room that was created by me and I don't know how can I delete this chat room.

So please help me by giving me guidelines about the deleting the chat room that was created by me.

Comment: If you don't post anything inside for few days, the chat room will be automatically frozen. See: http://chat.stackexchange.com/faq#retention

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just stop using the room. It'll be deleted or frozen (depending on how much it was used) automatically after either 7 or 14 days.

See the [Chat FAQ](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/faq#retention):

> Rooms will exist indefinitely, so long as there is at least one person actively talking in the room. A room is considered worth retaining if it has more than 15 messages by at least 2 users.
>
> Rooms not worth retaining which are inactive for 7 days will be **deleted**. Rooms worth retaining which are inactive for 14 days will be **frozen**. Frozen rooms do not allow any new messages to be sent, and are not shown in the default room list to prevent cluttering the rooms interface.

Note that 3 of the rooms you created on [chat.stackoverflow.com](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/1035257/gaurav-vashishtha) have fewer than 15 messages in them, those will all be deleted in 7 days time if you don't add any more messages to them. The 4th one will be frozen in 14 days time; there are more than 15 messages by 2 people in that room.

You can always switch the room access level to 'Gallery' (room info -> Access tab) to prevent people from talking in a room you want to see frozen or deleted.

There is no option available for explicitly deleting a room. Don't use Stack Exchange chat rooms for conversations that you expect to be private.